# "PL/SQL: Function returned without value" A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was executed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've created a PL/SQL package with functions but when the package is called by passing the input values, then I get the following message:

**`Error report:`
`ORA-06503: PL/SQL: Function returned without value`
`ORA-06512: at "APPDATA.PWH_RELEASE_PAYMENT_ORDER_PKG", line 107`
`ORA-06512: at "APPDATA.PWH_RELEASE_PAYMENT_ORDER_PKG", line 158`
`ORA-06512: at line 36`
`06503. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: Function returned without value"`
`*Cause:    A call to PL/SQL function completed, but no RETURN statement was executed.*Action:   Rewrite PL/SQL function, making sure that it always returns a value of a proper type.`**

**Here's the package call being run:**

```
/*  Type Bank ID Collection  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_BANKID_COLL
FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(35 CHAR);                        -- Type BankId Collection
/

/*  Type processing line collection  */
create or replace TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINE_COLL FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);        
/

/*  Type processing line ID collection  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL FORCE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

/*  Type Processing line flows - Object type 1  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS FORCE AS OBJECT 
(
    processinglineid NUMBER,
    processinglineflow TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW
);
/
-- 2 data types

/*  Type Processing line flows coll - Nested table of Object type 1  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL  FORCE AS TABLE OF TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS;
/
-- Type Processing line flows Collection


/*  Type Processing line payment - Object type 2 */
create or replace TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMENT FORCE AS OBJECT
( 
  processingline      VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
  processingLineFlows TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW_COLL,
  messages            TYPE_MESSAGE_COLL,                            
  reservationRefs     TYPE_RSVDTLS_COLL
);
/

/* Type Processing line payment Collection - Nested table of Object type 2 */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMT_COLL FORCE AS TABLE OF TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMENT;
/

/*  Type Bank due payment - Object type 3 */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT FORCE AS OBJECT 
(
    bankid VARCHAR2(35 CHAR),
    payments TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMT_COLL
)
/

/*  Type Bank due date payment Collection - Nested table of Object type 3 */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT_COLL FORCE AS TABLE OF TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT;
/

/*  Type POR Due date process  */
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_PORDUEDATEPROCESS FORCE AS OBJECT 
(  
    duedateid   NUMBER,
    payments    TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT_COLL     
); 
/
```

**Here's the package code:**

```
/* Start of package header - pwh release payment order pkg */
create or replace PACKAGE pwh_release_payment_order_pkg AS
      /* 
        ======================================================================================
        Constants
        ======================================================================================
      */
        c_readyForReservationEngine         CONSTANT CHAR(4) := 'RFRE';         -- ready for reservation engine
        c_readyForPaymentEngine             CONSTANT CHAR(4) := 'RFPE';         -- ready for payment engine

      -- releaseProcessOrder
        FUNCTION releaseProcessOrder (
            p_processinglines TYPE_PROCESSINGLINE_COLL,                             -- p_processinglines : TYPE_PROCESSINGLINES
            /*
                create or replace TYPE TYPE_PROCESSINGLINE_COLL FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50 CHAR);    
            */
            p_portype         VARCHAR2,                                             -- Type BankID Collection                                               
            p_banksinprocess  TYPE_BANKID_COLL,                                     -- Banks in process
            /*
                From the types file:
                CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TYPE_BANKID_COLL
                FORCE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(35 CHAR);                
            */
            p_releasedate       paymentinfo.releasedate%type,                           -- Release Date
            p_paymentstatuses   TYPE_PAYMENT_STATUS_COLL,                               -- Payment Statuses
            p_processingdate    duedateprocess.processingdate%type                      -- Type release payment order  
        ) RETURN TYPE_PORDUEDATEPROCESS;  


/*  End of the package header */  
END pwh_release_payment_order_pkg;                                          
/
/* End of package header - End of pwh release payment order pkg */

/* Start of package body */
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pwh_release_payment_order_pkg
AS
        FUNCTION getRsvDtlsForTransactions(                                         /*  get Reservation Details For Transactions  */
            p_transactionIds TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL 
            ) RETURN TYPE_RSVDTLS_COLL                                                  /*  Type reservation details collection  */                         
        IS
            v_reservationDetails TYPE_RSVDTLS_COLL := TYPE_RSVDTLS_COLL();          /*  v_reservationDetails  */
            BEGIN
                SELECT TYPE_RSVDTLS( reservationreference, reservationtime, reservedamount, currencycode, fk_transactionsid ) BULK COLLECT
                /*  


                */
                INTO v_reservationDetails
                FROM reservation_details rsvd           
                INNER JOIN TABLE(p_transactionIds) tids                             /*  p_transactionIds - tids  */
                ON rsvd.fk_transactionsid = tids.COLUMN_VALUE;                      
                RETURN v_reservationDetails;                                            /*  return v_reservationdetails */
            END;

        FUNCTION getProcessingLineFlows(                                        
            p_processingLineIds IN TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL,              
            v_status OUT VARCHAR2
        )RETURN TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL
        AS
            v_processinglineflows TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL(); 
            v_cnt NUMBER;  
            v_processingLineIds TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL();             
            BEGIN
                SELECT TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS(fk_processinglineid, TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW( FUNCTION, component )) BULK COLLECT
                INTO v_processingLineFlows
                FROM processinglineflow flow                                                
                INNER JOIN TABLE (p_processingLineIds) p
                ON flow.fk_processinglineid = p.COLUMN_VALUE;

                SELECT COUNT(flw.processinglineflow.function)                               
                INTO v_cnt
                FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw                                  
                WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'FUND_CHECK';                       

                IF v_cnt                              = p_processingLineIds.count THEN  
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT flw.processinglineflow.component)                     
                INTO v_cnt
                FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw
                WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'FUND_CHECK';                   

                IF v_cnt                              = 1 THEN                              
                    v_status                           := c_readyForReservationEngine;  
                    RETURN v_processingLineFlows;                                                                           
                END IF;
                ELSIF v_cnt = 0 THEN                                                        
                    SELECT COUNT(flw.processinglineflow.function)                           
                    INTO v_cnt                                                                                                                          
                    FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw                                  
                    WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'PE_SELECTION';         

                    IF v_cnt                              = 1 THEN                                                      
                        v_status                           := c_readyForPaymentEngine;      
                        RETURN v_processingLineFlows;
                    END IF;
                    ELSE
                        raise_application_error (-20301, 'Invalid processing lines');           
                    END IF;
            END;



        FUNCTION releaseProcessOrder(
            p_processinglines   TYPE_PROCESSINGLINE_COLL,                                                           
            p_portype           VARCHAR2,                                                                           
            p_banksinprocess    TYPE_BANKID_COLL,                                                                   
            p_releasedate       paymentinfo.releasedate%type,                                                       
            p_paymentstatuses   TYPE_PAYMENT_STATUS_COLL,                                                           
            p_processingdate    duedateprocess.processingdate%type 
            )RETURN TYPE_PORDUEDATEPROCESS                                                                              
            AS
                v_status              VARCHAR2(4 CHAR);                                                                 
                v_functionFundsCheck  CHAR(10)                  := 'FUND_CHECK';                                            
                v_updatedTransactions TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL  := TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL();                                
                v_transactionids        TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL  := TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL();                          
                v_transactionidsforpl TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL  := TYPE_TRANSACTIONID_COLL();                                
                v_processinglineids     TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL();
                v_dueDateProcessId  duedateprocess.duedateprocessid%type;                                               
                v_processingLineFlows TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL();                 
                v_payments          TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT_COLL  := TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT_COLL();                    

                v_releasepaymentorder TYPE_PORDUEDATEPROCESS;                                                                    
                v_flw               TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW_COLL();                      
                v_duepay                TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMENT;                                                         
                v_duepayments       TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMT_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMT_COLL();                   
                BEGIN
                    SELECT p.processinglineid BULK COLLECT                                                                  
                    INTO v_processinglineids                                                                                     
                    FROM processingline p                                                                                        
                    INNER JOIN TABLE(p_processinglines) pl                                                                  
                    ON p.processingline    = pl.COLUMN_VALUE;                                                                   
                    v_processingLineFlows := getProcessingLineFlows(v_processinglineids,v_status);                          
                    v_dueDateProcessId := DUEDATE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;                                                               
                    INSERT
                    INTO duedateprocess                                                                                     
                    (
                        duedateprocessid,                                                                                        
                        processingdate,                                                                                     
                        fk_processinglineid
                    )                                                                                                       
                    SELECT v_dueDateProcessId,                                                                              
                    NVL(p_processingdate,SYSDATE),
                    p.COLUMN_VALUE                                                                                          
                    FROM TABLE (v_processinglineids) p;     

                    SELECT TYPE_PORDUEDATEPROCESS(v_dueDateProcessId,TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT_COLL())                            
                    INTO v_releasepaymentorder                                                                               
                    FROM DUAL;

                    IF p_portype = 'PrioritizedPOR' THEN                                                                         
                        UPDATE transactions                                                                                     
                        SET paymentstatus     = v_status                                                                            -- If the por type is 'PrioritizedPOR',then paymentstatus is set to 'v_status'
                        WHERE paymentstatus  IN ('RFDD','LAFU','TERE')
                        AND riskStatus IS NULL
                        AND fk_processinglineid IN (SELECT l.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_processinglineids)l)                          
                        AND fk_paymentinfoid IN
                        (SELECT paymentinfoid                                                                                   -- Select paymentinfo ID INNER JOIN the message table                                                                                   
                        FROM paymentinfo p                                                                  
                        INNER JOIN MESSAGE m                                                                                    
                        ON m.messageid         = p.fk_messageid                                                                 -- Message m
                        AND p.releasedate       <= SYSDATE                                                                      -- releasedate is the current date
                        AND m.markettype        = 'BM'                      
                        AND p.prioritized   = 'Y'                               
                        AND p.paymentmethod IN ('TRF') AND categorypurposecode = 'INTC' 
                        AND (p_banksinprocess IS NULL
                        OR initiatorbankid    IN
                        (SELECT b.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_banksinprocess) b
                        ))
                        ) RETURNING transactionsid BULK COLLECT                                                                 -- RETURNING transactionsid BULK COLLECT into v_updatedTransactions
                        INTO v_updatedTransactions;


                    ELSIF p_portype = 'CompletePOR' THEN
                        UPDATE transactions
                        SET paymentstatus     = v_status  
                        WHERE paymentstatus  IN ('RFDD','LAFU','TERE')
                        AND riskStatus IS NULL
                        AND fk_processinglineid IN (SELECT l.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_processinglineids)l)
                        AND fk_paymentinfoid IN
                        (SELECT paymentinfoid
                        FROM paymentinfo p
                        INNER JOIN MESSAGE m
                        ON m.messageid         = p.fk_messageid
                        AND p.releasedate       <= SYSDATE
                        AND m.markettype       = 'BM'    
                        AND (p_banksinprocess IS NULL
                        OR initiatorbankid    IN
                        (SELECT b.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_banksinprocess) b
                        ))
                        ) RETURNING transactionsid BULK COLLECT
                        INTO v_updatedTransactions; 


                    ELSIF p_portype IS NULL THEN 
                        UPDATE transactions
                        SET paymentstatus = v_status
                        WHERE paymentstatus IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(p_paymentstatuses))
                        AND riskStatus IS NULL
                        AND fk_paymentinfoid IN (
                            SELECT paymentinfoid 
                            FROM paymentinfo 
                            WHERE releasedate <= p_releasedate 
                            AND fk_processinglineid = (SELECT l.COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_processinglineids)l) 
                        ) RETURNING transactionsid
                        BULK COLLECT INTO v_updatedTransactions;  
                    END IF;


                    IF v_updatedTransactions.COUNT = 0 THEN
                        raise_application_error (-20302, 'There are no payments to process for processing lines');
                    END IF;


                    INSERT INTO duedateprocesstotransactions (fk_duedateprocessid, fk_transactionsid)
                    SELECT v_dueDateProcessId, ut.COLUMN_VALUE 
                    FROM TABLE(v_updatedTransactions) ut;

                    SELECT TYPE_BANKDUEDATEPAYMENT(initiatorbankid,TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMT_COLL()) BULK COLLECT
                    INTO v_payments
                    FROM transactions t
                    INNER JOIN paymentinfo p
                    ON p.paymentinfoid = t.fk_paymentinfoid
                    INNER JOIN MESSAGE m
                    ON m.messageid = p.fk_messageid
                    INNER JOIN TABLE(v_updatedTransactions) tid
                    ON t.transactionsid = tid.COLUMN_VALUE
                    GROUP BY m.initiatorbankid;                 


                    FOR i IN v_payments.FIRST..v_payments.LAST
                        LOOP
                            SELECT tid.COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT
                            INTO v_transactionids
                            FROM transactions t
                            INNER JOIN paymentinfo p
                            ON p.paymentinfoid = t.fk_paymentinfoid
                            INNER JOIN MESSAGE m
                            ON m.messageid = p.fk_messageid
                            INNER JOIN TABLE(v_updatedTransactions) tid
                            ON t.transactionsid   = tid.COLUMN_VALUE
                            AND m.initiatorbankid = v_payments(i).bankid;   


                            FOR j IN v_processinglineids.FIRST..v_processinglineids.LAST
                                LOOP    
                                    SELECT TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEPAYMENT(processingline,TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW_COLL(),TYPE_MESSAGE_COLL(),TYPE_RSVDTLS_COLL())
                                    INTO v_duepay
                                    FROM PROCESSINGLINE
                                    WHERE processinglineid = v_processinglineids(j);      
                                    SELECT TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOW(plf.function,plf.component) BULK COLLECT
                                    INTO v_flw
                                    FROM processinglineflow plf
                                    WHERE fk_processinglineid IN
                                    (SELECT fk_processinglineid                         
                                    FROM transactions t                                 
                                    INNER JOIN TABLE(v_transactionids)ut                
                                    ON t.transactionsid       = ut.COLUMN_VALUE         
                                    AND t.fk_processinglineid = v_processinglineids(j)
                                    );
                                    v_duepay.processinglineflows := v_flw;              


                                     SELECT ut.COLUMN_VALUE BULK COLLECT
                                     INTO v_transactionidsforpl
                                     FROM transactions t
                                     INNER JOIN TABLE(v_transactionids)ut
                                     ON t.transactionsid       = ut.COLUMN_VALUE
                                     AND t.fk_processinglineid = v_processinglineids(j);


                                     v_duepay.reservationRefs := getRsvDtlsForTransactions(v_transactionidsforpl);
                                     v_duepay.messages := pwh_read_pkg.read_duedate_payments(v_transactionidsforpl);
                                     v_duepayments.EXTEND;          
                                     v_duepayments(v_duepayments.COUNT):= v_duepay;

                                END LOOP;

                            v_payments(i).payments := v_duepayments;                     
                        END LOOP;

                    v_releasepaymentorder.payments := v_payments;
                    RETURN v_releasepaymentorder; 
        END;                        
END pwh_release_payment_order_pkg;
/
```

**Why is the error getting generated ?**

Comment: It would be a lot better question if you would have used a proper indention. This way it is allmost impossible to even read your package.

Comment: @ Kevin Esche: The code is indented now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this is to have a value of the return type initialized at the start of the function and the last statement in the function should return it.

This way there is only one return statement and it is always called unless there is an exception.

There also appears to be an issue with the nesting of your IF statements.  They way they are nested does not guarantee that a RETURN statement will be reached.

The issue in your code is shown here where I abbreviate your code and annotate it.

```
FUNCTION getProcessingLineFlows(                                        
p_processingLineIds IN TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL,              
v_status OUT VARCHAR2)
RETURN TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL
  AS
v_processinglineflows TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL :=   TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEFLOWS_COLL();   
v_cnt NUMBER;  
v_processingLineIds TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL := TYPE_PROCESSINGLINEID_COLL();             

BEGIN                 

IF v_cnt = p_processingLineIds.count THEN  
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT flw.processinglineflow.component)                     
INTO v_cnt
FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw
WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'FUND_CHECK';                   

   IF v_cnt  = 1 THEN                                  
     v_status                           := c_readyForReservationEngine; 
      --return from middle of the function
      --hard to trace and debug   
      --and is the RETURN value initialized?
     RETURN v_processingLineFlows;                                                                     
   END IF;
   --if v_cnt is not 1 then nothing is returned from the branch above this
   --the nested if loops are hard to track
ELSIF v_cnt = 0 THEN                                                        
  SELECT COUNT(flw.processinglineflow.function)                         
  INTO v_cnt                                                                                                                        
  FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw                                    
  WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'PE_SELECTION';               
     IF v_cnt   = 1 THEN                                                        
        v_status                           := c_readyForPaymentEngine;
        --v_status is initialized but not necessarily your RETURN value        
        RETURN v_processingLineFlows;
     END IF;
 ELSE
    raise_application_error (-20301, 'Invalid processing lines'); 
    --if the no suitable values are found then nothing is returned          
END IF;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify: what is the benefit of a single `RETURN`?  It seems to me you still have to carefully control all the different code paths to ensure that each one correctly sets the return value.  It seems to me that not then returning immediately is just an opportunity for the correctly set return value to get overwritten later by mistake.  What exactly do you gain by having a single `RETURN`?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak It's all about debugging. A return statement does not tell you where in the function it returned from.  All you know is that you get a value, or not for this question.   See here where brighter minds than I describe this best practice https://books.google.ca/books?id=LyePdNEAjyIC&lpg=PA203&ots=tIRS3w-unX&dq=feuerstein%20single%20return%20pl%2Fsql&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=feuerstein%20single%20return%20pl/sql&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Refer the create function documentation to find the correct syntax of definition.

[CREATE FUNCTION : ORACLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that every possible code path in every function has a `RETURN`.  For example, in your `getProcessingLineFlows` function, you have a branch that starts:

```
IF v_cnt = p_processingLineIds.count THEN 
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT flw.processinglineflow.component)                     
    INTO v_cnt
    FROM TABLE (v_processinglineflows) flw
    WHERE flw.processinglineflow.function = 'FUND_CHECK';                   

    IF v_cnt                              = 1 THEN                                  
        v_status                           := c_readyForReservationEngine;    
        RETURN v_processingLineFlows;                                                                     
    END IF;
ELSIF v_cnt = 0 THEN                                                        
    ...
```

It is hard to read your code as formatted, but I believe that in the number of distinct `flw.processinglineflow.component` values is not exactly 1, then this function will exit without returning a value.  I have no idea about your data or whether it is possible for that value to be anything other than 1 (although, if it's not, why are you checking it?).  But this is the sort of code structure that causes the error you are asking about.

You need to do similar checks on all your code paths and make sure there is no way for any function to end without returning.

Comment: @ Matthew McPeak: The code is formatted and indented now.

Comment: Thanks, but did you read my answer?  I pointed out at least one structural problem in your code that could cause the error you are reporting.